# Show external List data to only logged user

Tags: external-list

How to show only elements from an External List, where login or names is the same as for the currently logged in user?

Comment: Please be clear what is needed.

Comment: I have got a External List, and I want to corelate by the Login or the Name and Surname of Worker. And when the User login for his account he will show only things on which record is his Login, or Name and Surname.

Comment: How did you got the External Content Type work? VS or SPD?

Answer (score 1):

This can be better done at the External Content Type level. In the ReadList method, get the current user and check with an if condition whether the username matches the current username before returning the IEnumerable or the collection.

Comment: Have You got any Turorial of it ? :)

Comment: Yes follow from here: http://www.malindesilva.net/2014/07/sharepoint-2013-external-list.html

Comment: But it is Visual Studio, not a Sharepoint Designer. I don't have Yet any Developement Studio Prepered.

Comment: MeybeI could it do by Filter too ?

Comment: Yes you may be able to do it with views. That is the option as of now. If you are making things work with views make sure you fill all the possible security gaps.

Comment: But in External List I don't See field a Loged User

Comment: If you have a user column in the External list, then you can filter that column by [Me]